# insert a YES or NO value in data file extracted from LDAP

Tags: powershell, ldap, ldap-query

I am having a hard time modifying my script to add a value of YES or NO to a new field named `Ismanager` in an LDAP user database I extract.

Since there is no way to tell if a user is manager or not in our data, The YES value would be inserted if the userid appears more that 1 time in the `managerldapuid` field and NO if it is not repeated.

The challenge would be on how to insert a query in the loop to do this compare task and return the YES/NO value to the final data extract.

```
  Write-Verbose "Querying Enterprise Directory for uid list..."
  $out = Search-Ldap "(&(uid=*)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))" ("uid")
  $totaluids = $out.entries.count
  Write-VerboseWithMinutes ("Processing {0} uids..." -f $totaluids)
  foreach ($uidentry in $out.entries) {
    $loopcount++
    $currentuid = $uidentry.attributes.uid[0]
    if ($loopcount % 100 -eq 0) {
      Write-VerboseWithMinutes ("  {0} uids processed..." -f $loopcount)
    }
    $result = Search-Ldap "(&(uid=$($currentuid))(RequiresEthicsTraining=TRUE))" ("uid","givenname","sn","mail","jobfunction","facilityname","title","managerldapuid","co","c","division","hiredate","hrsystemid","hraccounttype","exemptstatus")
    foreach ($entry in $result.entries) {
      try {
        manageremail = $null
        $manageruid = $entry.attributes.managerldapuid[0]
        if ($manageruid) {
          $managerresult = Search-Ldap "(uid=$manageruid)" ("uid","mail")
          $manageremail = $managerresult.entries[0].attributes.mail[0];
        }
      } catch {
        $manageruid = $null
        $manageremail = $null
      }
      $userdata += $entry |
                   select @{n='Employee ID';e={$_.attributes.uid[0]}},
                     @{n='Person ID';e={$_.attributes.hrsystemid[0]}},
                     @{n='First Name';e={$_.attributes.givenname[0]}},
                     @{n='Last Name';e={$_.attributes.sn[0]}},
                     @{n='Email';e={$_.attributes.mail[0]}},
                     @{n='Department';e={$_.attributes.jobfunction[0]}},
                     @{n='Ismanager';e={}},
    }
  }
  Write-VerboseWithMinutes ("Finished processing")
  $DataCsvName = "{1}\userdata-{0}.csv" -f ((get-date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")), $workdir
  Write-VerboseWithMinutes ("Exporting {0} users to CSV" -f $userdata.Count)
  $UserData | Export-CSV $DataCsvName -NoTypeInformation
}
```